# Docker and Prisma permission issues

Tags: docker, nestjs, prism

I have dockerized my NestJS and Prisma project but when I was done and pushed the changes to Github and tried to checkout to develop from my feature branch, I got this error.

**Error**

```
warning: unable to unlink 'server/prisma/migrations/20230622193702_init/migration.sql': Permission denied
fatal: cannot create directory at 'server/prisma/migrations/20230202185206_init': Permission denied
```

I then I ran `git status` and it looks like all the changes I've just pushed were unstaged again.

**My Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1 building the code

FROM node:18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /statrics-server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN yarn build



# stage 2

FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /statrics-server  

COPY --from=builder /statrics-server/dist ./dist

COPY --from=builder /statrics-server/node_modules ./node_modules/

COPY --from=builder /statrics-server/package*.json ./

COPY .env .

# Expose the necessary ports and start the application
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "dev-server"]
```

**My compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.9'
services: 
   api: 
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev      
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports: 
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - ./server:/statrics-server
      - ./server/dist:/statrics-server/dist
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

**git status ouput after getting the permission denied message**
[image]

I really can't checkout to another branch the way I usually do in other projects. What's wrong?